# Redux-Form: Field(Array) made up of 2 ore more fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-select

I have a (simple?) form that is supposed to build some data and send it to a backend. Within the data I have a property called `personnel`, which is an array holding objects in the form `{id: 123, name: "User", role: 'some_role'}`. The user should be able to select a person from a dropdown and the role from another and then press a button to push it to the array:

- `id` and `user` come from the user selecting from [`react-select`](https://react-select.com/home) wrapper for [`redux-form`](https://gist.github.com/leocristofani/98312e61807db8f32e720c9f97a186e5)
- `role` comes from another instance of a `react-select` wrapper

The problem I am facing now is piecing these two parts together and pushing them into the `personnel` field. How would I do that ?

In my component I have the following:

```
  renderSelect(formValues) {
    return <RFReactSelect {...formValues} />;
  } 
  ...
  onPersonnelSelected(personnel) {
    // this does nothing atm
  }
  ...
  render() {
        ...
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <FieldArray
                    name="personnel"
                    label="Personnel"
                    component={this.renderSelect}
                    options={this.props.members}
                    labelKey={option => option.name}
                    valueKey={option => option.id}
                    value={this.props.personnel}
                    onChange={this.onPersonnelSelected}
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <Field
                    name="role"
                    label="Role"
                    component={this.renderRoles}
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <label>&nbsp;</label>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    onClick={this.onPersonnelSelected}
                  >
                    Add Personnel
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
         }
```

My problem is that I do now know how to merge these 2 together when the user clicks on the button and push them to the `personnel` array.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using version 1 or version 2 of the `react-select` library?

Comment: @Rallen 2.3.0 .

Answer (score 0):

If each person can have its own role, I would redesign the form a bit, moving the `role` field *inside* the `this.renderSelect`.

Looking at the `FieldArray` [tutorial](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/fieldarray.md/), you have to map each field with a name like

```
// field 1
name={`${person}.name`}

// field 2
name={`${person}.role`}
```

So you are gonna have 2 Fields instead of 1.

In that way, when the `Add button` runs the `fields.push({})`, all the subfields will become properties of the pushed object.

To "connect" this logic to `react-select` I assume you can use `RFReactSelect` in place of `Field`

Comment: Will give it a try a bit later, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: how would you include the ID as well without adding a new field? The id comes from the selected option in `RFReactSelect` ? I understand the tutorial, but not quite clear how would I add the id, so the object has `{id, name, role}`. Thanks